# Ionic app - controller $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building a app in ionic, i am trying to get external restful api data into the view via a controller, but there seems to be something wrong with my controller because nothing is being pulled in?

my code is:

```js
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if(window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts').then(function(results){
  $scope.posts = results.data.posts;
  }, function(err) {
    console.error('ERR', err);
    // err.status will contain the status code
  })
});
```

```html
 <ion-content class="has-subheader" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat='item in posts' class="item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap">
          <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="photo">
          <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
          <h4>Place</h4>
          <p style="font-size:12px; line-height:16px;">Quisque quis sem a velit placerat vehicula quis nec felis. Mauris posuere, nisl vitae condimentum luctus, tellus enim blandit orci, quis efficitur nibh libero eget dui. Aliquam fermentum velit quis sem molestie.</p>

        </ion-item>
      </ion-list> 
    </ion-content>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you use .success ?

Comment: can you elaborate pls, i am pretty new to angular JS?

Comment: how do I add that so that you can run code within question?

Answer (score 1):

Solution to this:

```
$http.get('http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
.success(function(results){
    $scope.posts = results.posts;
    console.log($scope.posts);
});
```

You were using `data` but there isn't `data` in the results. Look at the console, and you should see objects now.

[Working codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpRPKa)

Comment: where abouts are you putting that, becuase that does not work for me?

Comment: Update: the html part is slightly wrong, it needs to read: <h2>{{item.title}}</h2> not with <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>

Answer (score 0):

you have made 2 mistakes in your code:

**First:** once you define 'item' in ng-repeat you should use it to bind your object key "title":

```
ng-repeat='item in posts'
```

> 'item' is now holding your JSON keys.

```
<h2>{{item.title}}</h2>
```

**Second:** reviewing *jsonplaceholder* JSON you are calling through this url, http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts, title key is under `results.data`
, so you should define posts like this:

```
$scope.posts = results.data
```

---

**For more help:** I've taken the code you provided and made it working on a plunk, check it on the following url:
http://embed.plnkr.co/Gp1U3y/preview

Please contact me for more help. Thanks

Comment: Would you please consider marking my answer as correct and give it a vote up. You are welcome :D